# StopNodeOrHaltFailureHandler configuration

Tags: ignite

I have got several questions about `StopNodeOrHaltFailureHandler` configuration:

1. Why the default behaviour is to halt an Ignite node?
2. What is the preferred value of `timeout` parameter in case of `tryStop` parameter is set to `true`?
3. It looks like it is not possible to change the default configuration of `StopNodeOrHaltFailureHandler` via xml. I have tried configuration below and got an error

   > Error setting property values; nested exception is 
   >   org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'tryStop' of bean cl
   >    property 'tryStop' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?

   Where can I create the issue and offer a pull request with a fix?

```
<property name="failureHandler">
    <bean class="org.apache.ignite.failure.StopNodeOrHaltFailureHandler">
        <property name="tryStop" value="true"/>
        <property name="timeout" value="10000"/>
    </bean>
</property>
```

Answer (score 0):

From javadoc:

> Handler will try to stop node if `tryStop` value is true. If node can't be stopped during provided `timeout` or `tryStop` value is false then JVM process will be terminated forcibly using `Runtime.getRuntime().halt()`.

Default timeout is `0L` (endless wait).

`tryStop` and `timeout` are constructor arguments and should be configured as such in Spring XML.

Comment: That is all correct. The problem is that it cannot be configured with XML because of exception.

Comment: As I have said, you just have to use constructor args instead of properties. See https://www.baeldung.com/spring-xml-injection#2-using-constructor